# my friend asked me this and I was shaken on hearing the answer

Tags: riddle

I can kill you and not be punished,

Bring you back to life without any magic

I need neither legbiter nor excalibur

Cause my weapon's stronger than any other warrior's

Comment: The gnat is mightier than the sword

Comment: @humn haha not the answer but youre quite close!! look at the title!!

Comment: Demon's Soul's cursed weapon? ;)

Comment: @Anurag Gawd NO ahaha!! Everything matches except for the title! :/

Comment: A [death rattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_rattle) can stir (and shake) a soul at the last moment

Comment: @humn noppeee! :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you

> A writer

I can kill you and not be punished

> I can kill you in my story

Bring you back to life without any magic

> Same

I need neither legbiter nor excalibur

> Names of swords

Cause my weapon's stronger than any other warrior's

> Pen in my weapon and it is mightier than the sword

Title

> Shakes"peer(your friend)"--> writer

Comment: Lol! how did you the title part! ahaha Good one! :)

Comment: @starkgurl is that your intended answer? If yes, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark beside the answer

Comment: @Sid woah cool!! thanks! I just joined today lol!!

Answer (score 5):

> Electricity?

I can kill you and not be punished,

> Electric shock

Bring you back to life without any magic

> An electric shock can start your heart again

I need neither legbiter nor excalibur

Cause my weapon's stronger than any other warrior's

> It doesn't need another weapon, it's perfectly capable of killing you on the spot.

This also fits the title, as

> Electricity can make you shake (speaking from experience)

Comment: Nope!Not the answer! Sorry :(

Comment: I'm afraid that if you don't add some more lines to the riddle, it'll be closed, as there are too many answers. (I suspect that the answer is words, actually, but I won't answer at the moment.)

Comment: Ooh nice, this actually (IMO) fits better than the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing you are:

> Snake

I can kill you and not be punished,

> Of course, a snake can kill you. Snake bites are lethal.

Bring you back to life without any magic

> I think there is an idea that a snake can suck its own poison out of your body and save you?

I need neither legbiter nor excalibur

> Because a snake is a legbiter itself. It doesn't need another.

Cause my weapon's stronger than any other warrior's

> Maybe? Snake bites are very dangerous for all we know.

Comment: Haha Good try but not the answer!!

Comment: That sucking thing sounds bollywood :)

Comment: Shaken like a rattle(r)! I like this, @starkgurl (if that is your real name; "humn" isn't mine but it'll do).

Comment: @Tech that is why I said there is an "idea". :P

Comment: How about a vampire sn___?

Comment: @humn obv its not my real name! but got for life!!

Answer (score 4):

Are you:

> A pen?

I can kill you and not be punished,

> I can kill you off in my book/story and no law will be broken. (or my deathnote :P)

Bring you back to life without any magic

> Same as above, I can decide to bring your character back.

I need neither legbiter nor excalibur
Cause my weapon's stronger than any other warrior's

> A pen is mightier than the sword.

Comment: you're very close but its not the correct answer :/

Answer (score 0):

Is that

> **Air**?

> I can kill you and not be punished, **V**
>
> Bring you back to life without any magic  **V**
>
> I need neither legbiter nor excalibur  **V**
>
> Cause my weapon's stronger than any other warrior's  **V**

Comment: Could you explain why you believe your answer is a better match for the riddle than the currently accepted answer?

Comment: @F1Krazy, didn't notice theaccepted answer.